# Boolean Operators and ClientHandler

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to use clienthandlers to determine if 2 text boxes are either both empty or both contain a value but not one or the other?

At the moment I am using a serverhandler to test this condition but for speed I'd rather use clienthandlers.

```
if ((textbox1 == '' && textbox2 == '') || (textbox1 != '' && textbox2 != ''))
  //do something
else
  //display error 'both boxes must either be empty or contain a value
```

Cheers
Dave

Some example code:

```
function genObsReport() {
 var myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Report');   
 var dateFrom = myapp.createDateBox().setId("dateFrom");  
 var dateTo = myapp.createDateBox().setId("dateTo");   

 var mygrid = myapp.createGrid(2, 2); 
 mygrid.setWidget(0, 0, myapp.createLabel('Date from'));
 mygrid.setWidget(0, 1, dateFrom);
 mygrid.setWidget(1, 0, myapp.createLabel('Date to'));
 mygrid.setWidget(1, 1, dateTo);

 var errors = myapp.createLabel('Error').setId('errors').setVisible(false);  
 var mybutton = myapp.createButton('Create Report');

 var mypanel = myapp.createVerticalPanel();     
 mypanel.add(mygrid);
 mypanel.add(mybutton);

 mypanel.add(errors);
 myapp.add(mypanel);  

 var handler = myapp.createServerHandler("change");
 handler.addCallbackElement(mygrid);  
 mybutton.addClickHandler(handler);

 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 spreadsheet.show(myapp);  
}

function change(eventInfo) {
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();    
 var dateFrom = eventInfo.parameter.dateFrom;
 var dateTo = eventInfo.parameter.dateTo;

 // check the dates
 if ((dateFrom == '' && dateTo == '') || (dateFrom != '' && dateTo != '')) {
    //do something
 } else {
   //show errors
   app.getElementById('errors').setVisible(true);
   app.getElementById('dateFrom').setStyleAttributes({background: "red", color: "black"});
   app.getElementById('dateTo').setStyleAttributes({background: "red", color: "black"});
 } 
}
```

Comment: In your idea what would be the trigger source of the client handler?  It can't be the button nor any of the date boxes since when you click a date box it gets automatically a value... so I don't see how to implement it in your code even if it was possible ( which I doubt...)

Comment: an `addValueChangeHandler()` can be added to the date boxes to trigger a server function to run the validation sooner, but the problem with the date boxes is that once you throw a value in one and then clear it out, the value still remains.

Comment: Thanks Serge and Bryan. I see what you are both saying. I'll stick with my current solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it is possible - although what I came up with is certainly cludgy.
Here is my logic:

Given a texbox, add two clienthandlers that checks the length - one checks for 0 length the other for 1 or more.  Change the value in a hidden textbox to 0 or one depending on what happens.
Repeat this with a different hidden textbox for the second textbox.
create two new validators to enable or disable your button based on the sum of the two hidden textboxes.
Although it should work since the documentation says handlers are done in the order they are added, for extra safety,I added another handler on the button itself.  I threw up some nicer code [HERE](http://www.velofin.com/code-comments/2013/11/22/google-apps-script-client-validation) that adds some extra labels and formatting to make it more obvious but the code was getting a bit long for here so below pretty much the minimum of what you need.
[Here is the final working product](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwWM-bVDMKO7rtMQ3rPlhQ5WbSFzc7r2IXjf00QmVPYHicdQ00/exec) in action

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();


  var button = app.createButton('Click Me');
  app.add(button);

  var tb1=app.createTextBox().setId('tb1').setName('tb1');
  var tb2=app.createTextBox().setId('tb2').setName('tb2');
  //Hide these two - but i left them visible so you can see the script in action.
  var tbValidatorForTb1=app.createTextBox().setId('tb3').setName('tb3');
  var tbValidatorForTb2=app.createTextBox().setId('tb4').setName('tb4');
  var label = app.createLabel('The button was clicked.')
                 .setId('statusLabel')
                 .setVisible(false);
  app.add(label);
  app.add(tb1);
  app.add(tb2);

  app.add(tbValidatorForTb1);
  app.add(tbValidatorForTb2);
  //Set your validators for your first textbox
  var clientHandler1=app.createClientHandler().validateLength(tb1, 1, 200).forTargets(tbValidatorForTb1).setText('1');
  var clientHandler2=app.createClientHandler().validateLength(tb1,0, 0).forTargets(tbValidatorForTb1).setText('0');

  //Set your validators for your second textbox
  var clientHandler3=app.createClientHandler().validateLength(tb2, 1, 200).forTargets(tbValidatorForTb2).setText('1');
  var clientHandler4=app.createClientHandler().validateLength(tb2, 0, 0).forTargets(tbValidatorForTb2).setText('0');
  tb1.addKeyUpHandler(clientHandler1);
  tb1.addKeyUpHandler(clientHandler2);
  tb2.addKeyUpHandler(clientHandler3);
  tb2.addKeyUpHandler(clientHandler4);
  tb2.addKeyUpHandler(clientHandler1);
  tb2.addKeyUpHandler(clientHandler2);
  tb1.addKeyUpHandler(clientHandler3);
  tb1.addKeyUpHandler(clientHandler4);



  //Now create some client handlers to do the actual enable/disable of the button


  var finalDisableValidator=app.createClientHandler().validateSum([tbValidatorForTb1,tbValidatorForTb2], 1).forTargets(button).setEnabled(false);
  var finalEnableValidator=app.createClientHandler().validateNotSum([tbValidatorForTb1,tbValidatorForTb2], 1).forTargets(button).setEnabled(true);

  tb1.addKeyUpHandler(finalDisableValidator);
  tb1.addKeyUpHandler(finalEnableValidator);
  tb2.addKeyUpHandler(finalDisableValidator);
  tb2.addKeyUpHandler(finalEnableValidator);

  //tb4.addChangeHandler(finalEnableValidator)
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler').validateNotSum([tbValidatorForTb1,tbValidatorForTb2], 1);
  handler.addCallbackElement(label);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  return app;
}

function myClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var label = app.getElementById('statusLabel');
  label.setVisible(true);

  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

I missed the dateBox - so below is code that works for dateboxes.  A couple notes

1. lengthchecks on dateboxes don't work properly they throw an error
   for some reason. i used a regex testing for the '-' character.  you may need to change this if you've formated your date differently.
2. you need to fire events for invalid dates to handle
   empty fields
3. and lastly, you need to use the valuechange handler
   instead as it was correctly pointed out it doesn't have onkeyup

Below is the code for this

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();


  var button = app.createButton('Click Me');
  app.add(app.createLabel("This demonstrates using clienthandlers to require either neither or both fields to be populated before the button can be clicked"));
  var validationWarning=app.createLabel("Please enter a value in both fields or neither field").setId('warningLabel').setStyleAttribute('color', "red").setVisible(false);
  app.add(button);
  app.add(validationWarning);
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();


  // db1.addValueChangeHandler(handler);

  var tb1=app.createDateBox().setId('tb1').setName('tb1');
  var tb2=app.createDateBox().setId('tb2').setName('tb2');
  //Hide these two - but i left them visible so you can see the script in action.
  var tbValidatorForTb1=app.createTextBox().setId('tb3').setName('tb3').setEnabled(false);
  var tbValidatorForTb2=app.createTextBox().setId('tb4').setName('tb4').setEnabled(false);
  var label = app.createLabel('The button was clicked.')
                 .setId('statusLabel')
                 .setVisible(false);


  panel.add(label);

  var grid1=app.createGrid(2, 2);
  grid1.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel("Field 1"));
  grid1.setWidget(0, 1, app.createLabel("Field 2"));
  grid1.setWidget(1, 0,tb1);
  grid1.setWidget(1, 1,tb2);
  panel.add(grid1);

    var grid2=app.createGrid(2, 2);
  grid2.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel("Validator 1"));
  grid2.setWidget(0, 1, app.createLabel("Validator 2"));
  grid2.setWidget(1, 0,tbValidatorForTb1);
  grid2.setWidget(1, 1,tbValidatorForTb2);
  panel.add(grid2);

  app.add(panel);
  //Set your validators for your first textbox
//  var dateHandler1=app.createClientHandler().validateInteger(tb1).forTargets(tbValidatorForTb1).setText('1');
//  var dateHandler2=app.createClientHandler().validateInteger(tb1).forTargets(tbValidatorForTb2).setText('1');

  var clientHandler1=app.createClientHandler().validateMatches(tb1,'\-').forTargets(tbValidatorForTb1).setText('1');
  var clientHandler2=app.createClientHandler().validateNotMatches(tb1, '\-').forTargets(tbValidatorForTb1).setText('0');

  //Set your validators for your second textbox
  var clientHandler3=app.createClientHandler().validateMatches(tb2,'\-').forTargets(tbValidatorForTb2).setText('1');
  var clientHandler4=app.createClientHandler().validateNotMatches(tb2,'\-').forTargets(tbValidatorForTb2).setText('0');
  //tb1.addValueChangeHandler(handler)
   tb1.addValueChangeHandler(clientHandler1);
  tb1.addValueChangeHandler(clientHandler2);
  tb2.addValueChangeHandler(clientHandler3);
  tb2.addValueChangeHandler(clientHandler4);
 tb2.addValueChangeHandler(clientHandler1);
  tb2.addValueChangeHandler(clientHandler2);
 tb1.addValueChangeHandler(clientHandler3);
 tb1.addValueChangeHandler(clientHandler4);

  //Now create some client handlers to do the actual enable/disable of the button
  tb1.setFireEventsForInvalid(true);
    tb2.setFireEventsForInvalid(true);
  var finalDisableValidator=app.createClientHandler().validateSum([tbValidatorForTb1,tbValidatorForTb2], 1).forTargets(button).setEnabled(false).forTargets(validationWarning).setVisible(true);
  var finalEnableValidator=app.createClientHandler().validateNotSum([tbValidatorForTb1,tbValidatorForTb2], 1).forTargets(button).setEnabled(true).forTargets(validationWarning).setVisible(false);

  tb1.addValueChangeHandler(finalDisableValidator);
  tb1.addValueChangeHandler(finalEnableValidator);
  tb2.addValueChangeHandler(finalDisableValidator);
  tb2.addValueChangeHandler(finalEnableValidator);

  //tb4.addChangeHandler(finalEnableValidator)
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler').validateNotSum([tbValidatorForTb1,tbValidatorForTb2], 1);
  handler.addCallbackElement(label);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  return app;
}

function myClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var label = app.getElementById('statusLabel');
  label.setVisible(true);

  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

Comment: That's a great workaround! Thanks for taking the time to code it up.

Comment: nice job but the question was using dateBox, not TextBox... how would you handle that without keyup handler (dateBox don't have keyup handlers) ?

Comment: i updated my answer to handle dateboxes- don't know why my second code block is not getting formatted correcly :/